# JSP dynamic web page generation

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I am trying to build an application for our users, we need a correct design and right technologies. Here is the requirement. Based on user template selection we need to generate dynamic web pages, they should be constructed on fly and user enters/edits data and add some comments and he clicks "Save as TIFF".

My thoughts and questions.

1. Since we have around 100 templates with most of the layout and content is different.
   Generating jsp pages on fly for 100 templates is not an easy as in paper.
   I defined all our template attributes in XML and generated java objects using JAXB, 
   finally JSF to render XML data. Are we doing it correct or is there any better way?
2. Converting the generated JSP data to `tiff`. Once the user enter/edit data we convert the data to PDF using `JasperReports`. And Finally ICE Faces technology to convert it to `TIFF`.
   I feel we are doing some extra work converting the user entered data/ form data to `pdf` and then converting `pdf` to `TIFF`. Is there any better way to do this?

I am also looking at Velocity templates engine to see if that fits our requirement.

Thanks once again folks.

-SPD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With Velocity Engine you are on the right track because that provides the best way for dynamic view generation. If you want to make it more robust and cleaner you can use Spring MVC along with velocity view. SO that the Spring MVC will redirect to velocity view. You can also take a look at PDF view in spring MVC.
2. You can try using Apache Sanselan library(http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/) to generate images. Not sure if that satisfies your requirement but it does look promising.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Do you have any thoughts on #2 converting generated JSP to TIFF?

Comment: Edited my original answer for second question also(TIFF generation)